# Dynamically generating a flexible number of nested for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, dynamic

Is it possible to add/reduce number of nested for loops in a function based on the length of input?

For example:
Based on a certain input of length 3, I may need to use 1 nested for loop (for loop inside another for loop). Similar to this,

```py
for i in range(0, len(input)+1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(input)+1):
```

However, when the input length is 4, I could have achieved my result  if I could introduce additional for loop inside the already existing nested for loop, which means,

```py
for i in range(0, len(input)+1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(input)+1):
        for k in range(j+1, len(input)+1):`
```

Similarly, if the input length is 5, then I would like to introduce another for loop,

```py
for i in range(0, len(input)+1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(input)+1):
        for k in range(j+1, len(input)+1):
            for l in range(k+1, len(input)+1):`
```

The pattern is, there will be n-1 number of for loops for an input of length n.

Is it possible create such a function in Python?

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem. What is the real problem you are trying to solve ?

Comment: We could use an example. Recurrency fits here if applied properly.

Comment: For example, I have a list of numbers/alphabets as input.
Input = [1,2,3,4]
I want to create a combination of all the individual elements. Similar to following,
[1],[2],[3],[4],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4],[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]
Perhaps, there are different ways to solve the actual problem. But while trying to solve this I came up with the question of variable number of nested for loops.

Comment: @MarufSazed that being said, the question is a duplicate ;) Check the answers in the link

Comment: This is not a good dupe @RafaelC; this question is about a variable number of for loops whereas the alleged dupe you linked is about generation combinations.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque alright, will let the question open. But will just state the link to the correct solution for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements . Building variable number of for loops is a *terrible design*.

Comment: Again, not a good dupe @MarkDickinson

Answer (score 2):

From this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/759707/Generating-dynamically-nested-loops) the code written in C and hastily translated to python gives you this:

> If we look at how the nested loops work, we see that the inner most
>   loop works most of time and the upper loops are needed only when we
>   run out of values in the inner loops.
>
> To convert this into a dynamic nested loop we can represent the
>   different loop variables in an array. For simplicity lets assume that
>   the upper bound of these variables are a constant as in the above
>   example.
>
> To implement a dynamic nested loop we need to increment the inner most
>   loop variable until we run out values. Only then do we need to look at
>   changing the upper level loop variables.

While this snippet is generating combinatorics, it is maybe possible to imagine re-using it for a different purpose.

As mentioned in the comments, it may not be a good design choice.
There has to be a better (more pythonic) way using generators, or maybe async, than increasing the level of indirection.

Of course, there is also recursion, but that was not the point of the question.

### Generating dynamically nested loops

```
MAXROWS = 4      #    contains the number of levels
MAXVALUES = 2    #    contains the maximum combination for a given nested variables.

display = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

arrs = [0] * MAXROWS   # represent the different variables in the for loops                      
status = False

while not status: 

    total = 0
    # calculate total for exit condition
    for r in range(MAXROWS):
        total += arrs[r]
        # test for exit condition
    if total == (MAXVALUES - 1) * MAXROWS:
        status = True

    # printing
    for r in range(MAXROWS):
        print(display[arrs[r]], end=' ')  # print(arrs[r])
    print()

    # increment loop variables
    change = True
    r = MAXROWS-1    # start from innermost loop

    while change and r >= 0:
    # increment the innermost variable and check if spill overs
        if (arrs[r] + 1) > MAXVALUES-1:    
            arrs[r] += 1
            arrs[r] = 0     #  // reintialize loop variable
            # Change the upper variable by one
            # We need to increment the immediate upper level loop by one
            change = True   
        else:
            arrs[r] += 1
            change = False   # Stop as there the upper levels of the loop are unaffected

            # We can perform any inner loop calculation here arrs[r]

        r -= 1  #  move to upper level of the loop
```

#### output:

```
1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 2 
1 1 2 1 
1 1 2 2 
1 2 1 1 
1 2 1 2 
1 2 2 1 
1 2 2 2 
2 1 1 1 
2 1 1 2 
2 1 2 1 
2 1 2 2 
2 2 1 1 
2 2 1 2 
2 2 2 1 
2 2 2 2
```